# Prove that ${{n}\choose{r}}+{{n}\choose{r-1}}={{n+1}\choose{r}}$

Tags: combinatorics

Having a bit of trouble with what should be a fairly simple proof. Here's what I have. We want to show, $${{n}\choose{r}}+{{n}\choose{r-1}}={{n+1}\choose{r}}.$$ We rewrite this as, $$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}+\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1)!}.$$ However, this is the same as, $$\frac{n!}{r(r-1)!(n-r)!}+\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1)(n-r)!}.$$ Then changing to a common denominator, we have, $$\frac{n!(n-r+1)+n!(r)}{r(r-1)!(n-r+1)(n-r)!}.$$ This simplifies to, $$\frac{(n+1)!}{r!(n-r+1)(n-r)!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{r!(n-r+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{r!(n-(r-1))!},$$ which isn't the expected result. Pretty sure I'm doing something clumsy here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have turned a $+$ into a $-$ on the very final equality. That's it, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed something...
Hint:

$$n−(r−1) = (n+1)-r$$

Comment: Aha! Forgot it was ${n+1}\choose{r}$, and not ${n}\choose{r}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any computation. Ask your self on how many way can I select $r$ objects from set of $n+1$ object if one is black and others $n$ are white.